# Failed to open stream No such file or directory : Wordpress custom function with yaml_parse_file

Tags: php, wordpress, yaml

I'm trying to learn how to extract data from a yaml file inside of a custom Wordpress theme.

functions.php :

```
function require_plugins(){
   $yaml_data = yaml_parse_file(get_template_directory_uri() . '/pluginsInfo.yml',);
   var_dump($yaml_data);
};
```

But all I have is :

```
PHP Warning:  yaml_parse_file(http://wordpress2.local/wp-content/themes/new_theme/pluginsInfo.yml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/new_theme/functions.php on line 191
```

[my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxred.png)

Where is my error please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[yaml_parse_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-parse-file.php) takes a path, not an URI. So you should do

```
$yaml_data = yaml_parse_file(get_template_directory() . '/pluginsInfo.yml');
```